# Rails POST params empty after submit?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms

i have a strange rails 3.2 problem. when i submit a form like this:

```
<%= form_for @job, :url => job_preview_path do |f| %>
<dl>
  <dt><%= f.label :job_title, "Job Titel" %></dt>
  <dd><%= f.text_field :job_title %></dd>
  <dt>Checkbox please!</dt>
  <dd><%= f.check_box :extra_featured %> </dd>
</dl>
<%= f.submit "Submit" %></p>
<% end %>
```

where the action route is defined as

```
match 'job/preview' => 'jobs#preview', :as => :job_preview, :via => :post
```

the values of the POST params stay empty after submit except for the check_box value. In the action in my controller after the submit, I reassigned the params to the model, so I can reuse the params for saving the entry.

```
def preview
  @job = Job.new(params[:job])
end
```

any advice on this strange behaviour? am i blind and don't see the bug?

Comment: Look at the rendered html and make sure the title text field's html name is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you on Rails 3.2.3? One of the changes of Rails 3.2.3 to Active Record is that "Whitelist all attribute assignment by default." See [[ANN] Rails 3.2.3 has been released!](http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/3/30/ann-rails-3-2-3-has-been-released/)

Comment: so i looked into it and was not able to fix the error. it doesn't assign any of the post parameters...

Comment: Have you checked the log? The post parameters should be printed out. Or you can check if params[:job] has any data.

Comment: I can think of two possible reasons, 1) the browser didn't send the data, 2) Rack failed to parse the data.